# How i can installed the node js in windows 7 and wampserver 2.0

Tags: angularjs, node.js

How i can installed the NodeJS in windows 7 ?

i am using **PHP 5.4** and **wampserver 2.0** and i want to configure *node JS with angular JS*.

Comment: You seriously could not look this up on Google? https://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: i am not able to configure. i am always got error. i am new bee in this technology. Please help

Comment: Please add error message.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://nodejs.org/download/ to download Node. Note the current download page as v0.12.  This is a huge shift from v.0.10.  v0.12 doesn't work with some of the larger NPM modules out there.  To download an older version goto http://nodejs.org/dist/